# Aurelia Bundling error

Tags: aurelia

I am using a modified aurelia-navigation-skeleton to build my project (modified because I am also adding a servicestack backend).

First the error:

```
[16:33:59] Error tracing npm:crypto-browserify@3.11.0/example/bundle.js at file:///C:/MyProjectPath/jspm_packages/npm/crypto-browserify@3.11.0/example/bundle.js
        Error: Unable to calculate canonical name to bundle file:///test.js. Ensure that this module sits within the baseURL or a wildcard path config.
    at getCanonicalNamePlain (C:\MyProjectPath\node_modules\systemjs-builder\lib\utils.js:227:13)
    at getCanonicalName (C:\MyProjectPath\node_modules\systemjs-builder\lib\utils.js:150:19)
    at C:\MyProjectPath\node_modules\systemjs-builder\lib\trace.js:565:36
    at run (C:\MyProjectPath\node_modules\karma\node_modules\core-js\modules\es6.promise.js:87:22)
    at C:\MyProjectPath\node_modules\karma\node_modules\core-js\modules\es6.promise.js:100:28
    at flush (C:\MyProjectPath\node_modules\karma\node_modules\core-js\modules\_microtask.js:18:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

I am not using crpto-browserify myself so I assume it is a dependency somewhere either within the skeleton or within Aurelia itself.

Project layout:

```
ProjectRoot
-- build  (from skeleton)
  -- tasks
-- src (standard aurelia layout here)
  -- app.js/main.js/app.html
  -- views
  -- resources
  -- etc...
-- default.html
-- node_modules
-- jspm_packages
-- jspm.config.js
-- package.json
```

jspm.config.js

```
System.config({
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "typescript",
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },
  map: {
    "aurelia-animator-css": "npm:aurelia-animator-css@1.0.1",
    "aurelia-api": "npm:aurelia-api@3.1.1",
    "aurelia-authentication": "npm:aurelia-authentication@3.3.0",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper": "npm:aurelia-bootstrapper@2.1.1",
    "aurelia-dependency-injection": "npm:aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.0",
    "aurelia-dialog": "npm:aurelia-dialog@1.0.0-beta.3.0.1",
    "aurelia-fetch-client": "npm:aurelia-fetch-client@1.1.1",
    "aurelia-framework": "npm:aurelia-framework@1.1.0",
    "aurelia-pal-browser": "npm:aurelia-pal-browser@1.1.0",
    "aurelia-router": "npm:aurelia-router@1.2.1",
    "aurelia-templating-binding": "npm:aurelia-templating-binding@1.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "github:twbs/bootstrap@3.3.7",
    "font-awesome": "npm:font-awesome@4.7.0",
    "moment": "npm:moment@2.17.1",
    "numeral": "npm:numeral@2.0.4",
    "servicestack-client": "npm:servicestack-client@0.0.26",
    "text": "github:systemjs/plugin-text@0.0.9",
    "typescript": "npm:typescript@2.2.1",
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0": {
      "assert": "npm:assert@1.4.1"
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

bundle.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bundler = require('aurelia-bundler');
var bundles = require('../bundles.js');

var config = {
  force: true,
  baseURL: '.',
  configPath: './jspm.config.js',
  bundles: bundles.bundles
};

gulp.task('bundle', ['build'], function() {
  return bundler.bundle(config);
});

gulp.task('unbundle', function() {
  return bundler.unbundle(config);
});
```

bundles.js

```
module.exports = {
    "force": true,
    "packagePath": ".",
    "configPath": [             // SystemJS/JSPM configuration files
    "./jspm.config.js"
    ],
    "injectionConfigPath": "./jspm.config.js",
    "bundles": {
        "dist/app-build": {
            "includes": [
                "[**/*.js]",
                "**/*.html!text",
                "**/*.css!text"
            ],
            "options": {
                "inject": true,
                "minify": true,
                "depCache": false,
                "rev": true
            }
        },
        "dist/aurelia": {
            "includes": [
                "aurelia-api",
                "aurelia-authentication",
                "aurelia-framework",
                "aurelia-pal-browser",
                "aurelia-bootstrapper",
                "aurelia-dependency-injection",
                "aurelia-dialog",
                "aurelia-fetch-client",
                "aurelia-router",
                "aurelia-animator-css",
                "aurelia-templating-binding",
                "aurelia-polyfills",
                "aurelia-templating-binding",
                "aurelia-templating-resources",
                "aurelia-templating-router",
                "aurelia-loader-default",
                "aurelia-history-browser",
                "aurelia-logging-console",
                "moment",
                "numeral",
                "servicestack-client",
                "bootstrap",
                "bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!text"
            ],
            "options": {
                "inject": true,
                "minify": true,
                "depCache": false,
                "rev": true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The error means nothing to me and other posts about this error talk about changing the BaseURL, but I don't know what I would change it to to make this work.  Any help would be appreciated.